# how to prevent or block many requests in android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `Android` and `Firebase`
and I worry about that if a same user who is thinking bad trying request
over and over again. (by clicking, in `Firebase` repeat `get()` method)
it could be so much costable how do I prevent this?

Comment: Dear! Your question is not much clear. can you explain it more?

Comment: @IntsabHaider Sorry, I mean if you are in Instagram and you visit some other\`s page and then you press back button and then revisit that person\`s page again and again and again and again I mean it could be a lot of request out there if some bad guy has a bad mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very simple. Just Assume you are on registration screen Now you pressed a register button and waiting for response. Now you can disable button till you did not get response and when you get response either successful or unsuccessful then enable button to call registration function via register button again.

Comment: but registration\`s page is done when respond is come and intent to another activity. but what if like you read somebody\`s profile and close it and open again and close it and open again? and what if it would be like 1000 times in one hour

Comment: it is just simple bro you can save all data in sharedpreference in first time call. Now you can open and close profile 10000 times it will hit the server while cache or data not cleared by programmatically and user mannually.

Comment: I\`m sorry but I think it is still problem see I think "Shared Preferences"is used only for light-weight data, if my profile info? then it`s not problem but every time I read other people\`s profile? then it\`s gonna be a problem. because every time I have to store other people\`s profile data into Shared Preferences. right? or this is also no problem?

Comment: which type of data in profile and which cases you can use it.